# Referece internal nodes of pdf images generated by tikz in another tikz document

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have two images generated using tikz and saved as pdf files. Both had internal nodes that could be referenced at that time. My question is: is there a way to reference those internal nodes if I'm including them in a third document as PDF images?

Of course this mechanism is not needed for the MWE below, however the actual target is a more complex structure.

```
%% file1.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone};
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](1){1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

%% file2.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone};
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw](2){2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

%% file3.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone};
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[]at(-2,-2){\includegraphics{file1.pdf};
    \node[]at(+2,+2){\includegraphics{file2.pdf};
    %% here is the catch
    % \draw(1)--(2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`savebox` and friends could be a solution if they preserve the internal node references when transformations are applied (such as rotate or scale), which is not the case as far as I was able to test.

Comment: I have a solution using `\tikzmark` for *coordinates* but it means that you'd have to specify in advance where on the nodes the path should go, rather than using the node shape.  However the principle should be adaptable -- but it might need a new feature of `\tikzmark`.  Before I attempt that, can I confirm that you want to treat these nodes as full nodes rather than just reference a specific coordinate (that could be determined in advance)?

Comment: Hi, @LoopSpace! Thanks for taking a look at this question. In fact, I tried your nice tikzmark package before writing this question but I couldn't come up with a solution for what I wanted. Are you saying that your tikzmarks survive to the pdf generation? BTW: no, reference to coordinates seems to be enough. =)

Comment: Yes and no.  The information generated by `\tikzmark` is saved to the aux file of the relevant tex file, so inputting the aux files from the subdocuments would load in their tikzmark information.  It would then need a little bit of fiddling around with aligning origins to get them to line up, but all that information should be available so in principle that's possible.

Comment: Sounds neat, @LoopSpace! I have no idea how you are able to do that. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update 2019-12-16*: This ended up being merged into the [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package. The code below works almost *as-is* with one change: `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` instead of `\usetikzlibrary{savenodes}`.

---

(*2018-02-18: Update to take into account node transformations*)

While attempting a solution to this, I came across some code I'd written for [How to save and restore the nodes between tikzpictures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307356/86) about saving node information between tikz pictures.  To transfer this information between documents just needs some way to save and load it, and then a bit of thought about bounding boxes.

As this code is essentially in use in two answers, I've put it into a separate file and uploaded it to github.  You can download it from [this github repository](https://github.com/loopspace/savenodes).  At the moment, it's just a single file.

Here's an example based on your code.  I use `lualatex` by default, I've indicated the changes if you use `pdflatex`.  Note that I'm using the `filecontents` package to generate all of the files from one base file, if you're generating your files by a different method then you don't need these parts and you don't need the `\immediate\write18` lines.  This example needs running with the `--shell-escape` option because of this.

Here's the current example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415831/86}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{savenodes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%% file1.tex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-1.tex}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{savenodes,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[save nodes to file]
\node[draw,rotate=-30,save node](1) at (-2,0) {1};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1);
\node[draw,ellipse,save node] (c) at (current bounding box.center) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

%% file2.tex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-2.tex}
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{savenodes,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[save nodes to file]
\node[draw,rotate=-70,save node] (2) at (2,0) {2};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (2);
\node[draw,ellipse,save node] (c) at (current bounding box.center) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

%% file3.tex

%\immediate\write18{lualatex \jobname-1.tex}
%\immediate\write18{lualatex \jobname-2.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw,
  rotate=30,
  restore nodes from file={[transform saved nodes,name prefix=pic-1-]{\jobname-1}}
] (a-1) at (-2,-3) {\includegraphics{\jobname-1.pdf}};

\node[draw,
  rotate=70,
  restore nodes from file={[transform saved nodes,name prefix=pic-2-]{\jobname-2}}
] (a-2) at (+2,+2) {\includegraphics{\jobname-2.pdf}};

\draw[red] (pic-1-1.north west) --  (pic-1-1.north east) --  (pic-1-1.south east) --  (pic-1-1.south west) -- cycle;
\draw[red] (pic-2-2.north west) --  (pic-2-2.north east) --  (pic-2-2.south east) --  (pic-2-2.south west) -- cycle;

\node[red] at (pic-1-1) {1};
\node[red] at (pic-2-2) {2};

\draw (a-1) circle[radius=5pt];
\draw (a-2) circle[radius=5pt];

\draw (pic-1-1) -- (pic-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The interface is now via TikZ keys.  The ones defined are:

- `save nodes to file` on a scope, this says that any nodes marked to be saved in the scope should be saved to a file (called `\jobname.nodes`).  This is a boolean.  One of this or the next keys should be given (or both) to trigger the saving mechanism.
- `set node group=<group name>` on a scope, if not saving to a file then nodes are saved as a "node group", this sets the name.
- `save node` on a node, this marks that node as one to be saved (either to a file or a list).
- `restore nodes from file=<file name>`, this loads in the nodes saved from the given file.
- `restore nodes from list=<group name>`, this loads in the nodes saved from the given group.
- `transform saved nodes`, this means that the restored nodes are transformed with the last node's transformation (usually, this should be used if the `restore nodes from ...` is used on a node).
- `name prefix=...` this isn't a new key, but is a useful one.  The restored nodes pick up the `name prefix` and `name suffix` from TikZ's node naming system, so putting this key is a useful way to automatically add a prefix (or suffix) to each restored node name.  Note that if this is used *with* `transform saved nodes` then  the order matters: this must come *after* `transform saved nodes`.

Result:

[image: Loading node information]

The red nodes are overlaid on top of the original nodes.

Comment: Actually I always wanted to write to you about this. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391381/2388.

Comment: Thank you very much, @LoopSpace! It looks promising. You are using LaTeX 3, right? I guess I need to start to learn that... Quick questions. If I understood it right, you have to shift the coordinates as well the nodes by yourself, right? What does it happen to the references when you rotate the picture while inserting it in the document?

Comment: @tecepe That I'm using LaTeX3 needn't concern you unless you want to dig down into the code to see what's going on.  I find it much easier to write code using LaTeX3 than ordinary TeX/LaTeX so I tend to use that these days.  I'm working on the rotation part as I type ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm guessing you'd like the option to specify a non-aux file for the tikzmark data.  Sounds like a reasonable feature.  Could you open an issue for it on github?  https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark

Comment: I do have working code for it (I wrote it for a project), so I could sent it to you, I only need to find the time ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Even better!  Do send it to me.

Comment: I added an issue and will try to retrieve the code I have in the next week (you will perhaps have to adapt it a bit, but I guess you will manage).

Comment: @tecepe Now handles node transformations.

Comment: @LoopSpace: WOW! Really good! Thank you very much for your effort. BTW, I believe you developed a very good approach to avoid nested tikz pictures. =))) Thank you again!

Comment: Very impressive. I wouldn't have thought this could be (practically) done ....

Comment: Is there a reason why this never became official? This seems to be a *veeery* useful tool to have.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it is! I integrated it into tikzmark. I should update this answer to reflect that.